# Get mac_id from IP camera with RTSP protocol using python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, rtsp

I'm using OpenCV to read frames from IP camera using RTSP protocol in Python. Code snippet is given below-

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp_url")
frame = video_capture.read()
```

I can successfully able to connect and get the frames with the above code. Is it possible to get the MAC_ID, serial number and other details or only MAC_ID from IP camera?